# Render 'no content' component when section in SectionList component is empty

Tags: react-native

See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html

When one of the Section's is empty (e.a. the data prop is an empty array), I would still like to render the SectionHeader, but also render a component that indicates that the section contains no data.

I know for the FlatList component this is possible using the ListEmptyComponent prop, but how does this work for the SectionList component?

I was hoping for something like this (but it doesn't work):

```
<SectionList
    style={styles.container}
    renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <SectionHeader title={section.title} />}
    sections={[
      {
        data: Object.values(this.props.teams),
        title: 'Teams',
        renderItem: this._renderTeamItem,
        keyExtractor: item => item.id,
        ListEmptyComponent: this._renderEmpty
      },
      {
        data: Object.values(this.props.invites),
        title: 'Invites',
        renderItem: this._renderInviteItem,
        keyExtractor: item => item.id,
        ListEmptyComponent: this._renderEmpty
      }
    ]}
  />
```

Answer (score 58):

You could use the renderSectionFooter to display any 'no content' component. Check out the following little example:

```
<SectionList
   renderSectionFooter={this.renderNoContent}
   section={[
      {data: ['1', '2']},
      {data: []}
   ]}
/>

renderNoContent = ({section}) => {
   if(section.data.length == 0){
      return NO_CONTENT_COMPONENT
   }
   return null
}
```

Comment: Could be a nice feature to have. Something like `renderEmptySectionComponent`.

Comment: You can change `renderSectionFooter={({section}) => this.renderNoContent(section)}` to `renderSectionFooter={this.renderNoContent}` to avoid extra renders.

Comment: Can data in section be a component instead of an array?

Answer (score 12):

I'm little late for the party, but since I just had to do this and I wasted a little more time on it than I'm comfortable admitting, I'll try to wrap everything up.

You can't use SectionList's `ListEmptyComponent` to achieve this as you do with the FlatList component. `ListEmptyComponent`is only triggered when the data prop is empty. If however you have any section in the data prop, then `ListEmptyComponent` won't be triggered.

One of the replies suggests using `renderItem` and checking inside of it whether section.data.length equals 0. That's nice idea, except that `renderItem` won't be called for sections that have `data.length === 0`. **So this approach won't work.**

What you are left with is either using `renderSectionHeader`or `renderSectionFooter` - which one you decide to use is up to you and your specific use case.

The `renderSection*`function receives the section and there you are able to check whether the section has a data prop with length > 0. If it doesn't this would be your chance to output an EmptyComponent.

With the specific example in the question it would look something like this:

```js
<SectionList
    style={styles.container}
    renderSectionHeader={({section}) => {
      if (section.data.length === 0) {
        return section.ListEmptyComponent     
      }
      return <SectionHeader title={section.title} />

    }
    sections={[
      {
        data: Object.values(this.props.teams),
        title: 'Teams',
        renderItem: this._renderTeamItem,
        keyExtractor: item => item.id,
        ListEmptyComponent: this._renderEmpty
      },
      {
        data: Object.values(this.props.invites),
        title: 'Invites',
        renderItem: this._renderInviteItem,
        keyExtractor: item => item.id,
        ListEmptyComponent: this._renderEmpty
      }
    ]}
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<SectionList
    style={styles.container}
    renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <SectionHeader title={section.title} />}
    sections={[
      {
        data: Object.values(this.props.teams),
        title: 'Teams',
        renderItem: this._renderTeamItem,
        keyExtractor: item => item.id,
        ListEmptyComponent: this._renderEmpty
      },
      {
        data: Object.values(this.props.invites),
        title: 'Invites',
        renderItem: this._renderInviteItem,
        keyExtractor: item => item.id,
        ListEmptyComponent: this._renderEmpty
      }
    ].filter(s => s.data.length > 0)}
  />
```

try to filter out empty sections :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy way. And you will get all the Components except the Component that renders the data.

```
const myData = items?.length ? DATA : [] 

<SectionList
        sections={myData}
        keyExtractor={getKeyExtractor}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
        ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
        ListFooterComponent={renderFooterComponent}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation of React Native, ListEmptyComponent is the props provided for SectionList, but it will work only if we pass an empty array to section.data

```
    <SectionList
    sections={ filteredData ?? []}>
```

This should render Empty component written under ListEmptyComponent Props in case of no response or blank data

[SectionList_React_Native_Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist#listemptycomponent)

Answer (score -2):

Should work in the exact same way I believe: [listEmptyComponent](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html#listemptycomponent)

Alternatively you could also do a conditional in your JSX to render the message for there being no data

Comment: The ListEmptyComponent gets rendered when the list of sections provided is empty, not when one of the sections is empty.

A conditional might work, but that code would soon become bulky. I was hoping that there was a way to do it just like the listEmptyComponent, but for empty sections instead. Like passing in a ListEmptyComponent for each of the sections