# React native list empty component not working in section list

Tags: javascript, list, react-native

I am trying to render empty component when my sections are empty. This is the sample code of mine

```
<SectionList
    sections={[
        {title: 'sectionOne', data: this.props.Activities.ActivityTypeOne},
        {title: 'sectionTwo', data: this.props.Activities.ActivityTypeTwo},
        {title: 'sectionThree', data: this.props.Activities.ActivityTypeThree}
    ]}
    keyExtractor={ (item, index) => index }
    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={true}
    extraData={this.state}
    ListEmptyComponent={this.renderEmptyScreens}
    />
```

But when this  3 all arrays are empty, it does not trigger the `ListEmptyComponent`
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code, or if my logic is incorrect can anyone please explain me.
Bacically I need to render some view when all 3 arrays are empty.

Comment: Where do you get `sectionList` from?

Comment: I did not get it @vencovsky

Comment: Now with your edit, I see where you get it from. Please show the case where it's nothing working. Please show how is `But when this 3 all arrays are empty`

Comment: Your list isn't empty, it contains three sections. The fact that these sections are empty isn't relevant.

Comment: this.props.Activities.ActivityTypeOne, this.props.Activities.ActivityTypeTwo, this.props.Activities.ActivityTypeThree when this  lists are empty I need to display another view

Comment: @nit ya this.props.Activity is an object. inside that object there are 3 arrays. but in my case my all arrays are empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After running into this problem myself, I discovered that the `sections` property has to be *completely* empty for the list to be considered empty (aka, `sections` itself should equal to `[]`).

**Solution:**

Use a ternary operator to choose what to pass into `sections` based on your own criteria. If it's decided to be empty, pass in `[]`, else pass in your sections object. As an example, your code would look something like this:

```
isSectionsEmpty(sectionsObject){
    //logic for deciding if sections object is empty goes here
}

render(){
    /* ...
       Other render code
       ...
    */
    const sections = [
        {title: 'sectionOne', data: this.props.Activities.ActivityTypeOne},
        {title: 'sectionTwo', data: this.props.Activities.ActivityTypeTwo},
        {title: 'sectionThree', data: this.props.Activities.ActivityTypeThree}
    ]
    return(
        ...
        <SectionList
            sections={this.isSectionsEmpty(sections) ? [] : sections}
            keyExtractor={ (item, index) => index }
            stickySectionHeadersEnabled={true}
            extraData={this.state}
            ListEmptyComponent={this.renderEmptyScreens}
            />
        ...
    )
}
```

*Note:* You could also forego the ternary operator and directly return either your sections object or `[]` from `isSectionsEmpty`, but this method allows for you to check if sections is "empty" elsewhere in your code, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a section footer component in which you will render your empty screen based on `section.data.length`

For a little example see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48625428)

Comment: Thank you @Alexandru for the your answer. If I use like that it will gives each view for each empty section. So in my case it gives 3 views